# TileMill: inset line with negative line-offset property value produces strange artifacts

Tags: tilemill, mapnik

I'm trying to create an inset line in TileMill within a polygon using a negative value with the `line-offset` property.  However, it looks like the a line's cap doesn't get shifted, causing strange artifacts to appear on the outside of each polygon.  Guessing it has something to do w/ how mapnik handles `line-offset`.

See the bottom left corner of each polygon in following image

[image]

produced by the following cartocss code:

```
@mining: #f1dd06;
#mining {
  polygon-fill: @mining;
  polygon-opacity: 0.6; 
  line-color:#666;
  line-width:0.8;
  ::doublestroke{
    line-cap: butt;
    line-color: @mining;
    line-comp-op: multiply;
    line-opacity:0.8;
    line-width: 6.0; 
    line-offset: -3.0;
  }
}
```

Curious to know:

1. if there's a way around this by writing better carto, or if not?
2. if there's some other way around it, possibly by doing some pre-processing on the source data?

Comment: The problem is actually [this one](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/1382) I think, also described [here](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/issues/481).  The problem was fixed in Mapnik 3.